# Proving that nowhere dense implies totally disconnected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I know that totally disconnected does not imply nowhere dense,then what about the reverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take $\mathbb{R}$ as the $X$-axis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Also note that being totally disconnected is a topological property, while being nowhere dense is not a topological property, it depends on the overlying space ($\mathbb{R}$ is not nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$ while it is in $\mathbb{R}^2$). Such dependent property cannot imply a topological property.

Comment: Your answer really helps me a lot,Thanks!